# Using Power Query, how can I convert a JSON file that contains records of different data types into multiple tables, one for each datatype?

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

For example, I have the following JSON file:

```
[ 
    { 
        "DataType":"DataType_A", 
        "JSON":"{\"x\":\"0\", \"y\":\"1\", \"z\":\"2\"}"
    }, 
    { 
        "DataType":"DataType_A", 
        "JSON":"{\"x\":\"1\", \"y\":\"3\", \"z\":\"0\"}" 
    }, 
    { 
        "DataType":"DataType_B", 
        "JSON":"{\"Name\":\"steve\", \"Id\":\"4b\"}" 
    }, 
    { 
        "DataType":"DataType_B", 
        "JSON":"{\"Name\":\"andy\", \"Id\":\"7c\"}"
    },
    { 
        "DataType":"DataType_C", 
        "JSON":"{\"Address\":\"123 Anywhere St.\", \"Town\":\"Springfield\"}"
    },
    { 
        "DataType":"DataType_C", 
        "JSON":"{\"Address\":\"1400 Another Rd.\", \"Town\":\"Anytown\"}"
    }
]
```

I can import the file via the Get Data > From JSON function, resulting in this table:

```
    |  DataType  |                             JSON                      |
    | DataType_A | {"x":"0", "y":"1", "z":"2"}                           |
    | DataType_A | {"x":"1", "y":"3", "z":"0"}                           |
    | DataType_B | {"Name":"steve", "Id":"4b"}                           |
    | DataType_B | {"Name":"andy", "Id":"7c"}                            |
    | DataType_C | {"Address":"123 Anywhere St.", "Town":"Springfield" } |
    | DataType_C | {"Address":"1400 Another Rd.", "Town":"Anytown" }     |
```

How do I go from the table I have to 3 tables, one for each data type?

Comment: Power Query is able to breakdown a JSON file into tables with correct datatypes. What happened there? Did you use the JSON connector, on Get Data?

Comment: Okay, but I'm not understanding very well. How did you import the data to PBI?